# python shebang and path

Tags: python-3.x, path, shebang

I tried to execute a python script which starts with shebang(`#!/usr/bin/env python`) and got an error message :

> ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

when I type `which python` on prompt, this is the path : `/Users/kimseunghee/anaconda3/bin/python`

miss match of python path occured error message, in my guess...

if it's true, what should I do?

thanks.

Comment: It looks it's using the Python shipped with Anaconda. Have you tried installing Django in Anaconda? I believe you could do this with `conda install -c anaconda django`.

Comment: @mshindal actually, I ran the script by some guide of django and the command was python manage.py migrate. nevertheless, you think installing django with the command you recommend would solve the problem? and I already install django : `pip install django~=1.11.0`

Comment: What is the output of `which pip`?

Comment: @mshindal `/Users/kimseunghee/anaconda3/bin/pip`

Comment: I solve the problem: 1. change path of shebang to real python path 2. deactive venv and activate again 3. execute the script